Isn't the first requirement for NP-completeness redundant?
I am kinda learning but now that i have studied a lot about complexity theory, isn't the fact that if a problem in NP is Karp-reducible to a problem A then that means A is in NP too, so why do we need A to be in NP in the first place? 
(Btw when i look at the definition for reducible here, they are saying many-one reducible aka Karp-reducible)

"if a problem in NP is Karp-reducible to a problem A then that means A is in NP too" You have that exactly backwards. Remember, "X is (Karp-)reducible to Y" means roughly "Y is at least as hard as X" - complexity classes are (generally) preserved downwards, not upwards, with respect to Karp reductions.

@NoahSchweber Thanks, i got that confused you are right, thanks for the clarification anyways!
